# ¿Se puede unir JSP y Node JS para backend?

Tags: nodejs, jsp

Estoy usando *Node JS* para *backend*.

¿Es posible utilizar *JSP* para recibir los datos de un formulario, y *Node JS* para otro?

Comment: con que finalidad?

Comment: Pues es algo para la universidad me piden que lleve jsp por lo menos un formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Json podes compartir datos en distintos lenguajes, como es tu caso (Java y Javascript(Node))

Comment: Ando usando mongo como base de datos olvide mencionarlo

Comment: Como te dije arriba, independiente del lenguaje o tecnología que utilices, las puedes comunicar con un Json o también un XML

Comment: Hola Alexis como comenta Juan te recomiendo usar JSON aqui tienes un tutorial sobre Json espero que te sirva : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp    igualmente aqui tienes un video(en ingles) de una introduccion de Node JS con JSON: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqMIyTH9wSg    Espero que te sirva amigo.